# trying to write @media screen if screen size is 768px iPad portrait view, then right column stack down

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am designing playing around with bootstrap fluid layout. Here is my design:
http://www.getaveo.com/_bootstrap4/_delete.html

I have:

```
span3 (gray)
span6 (orange)
span3 (red)
```

I would like this to happen...

1 of 2) I am trying to write @media screen if screen size is 768px iPad portrait view, then:

Right column, span3 (red) stack down, and becomes 100%.
Orange column, span6 (orange) expands over or widen over more to the right edge. Or span6 becomes span9.
Left column, span3 (gray) stays the same.

Or it becomes something like this:

http://www.getaveo.com/_bootstrap4/_delete2.html

2) Now view _delete html again...

Make the your browser window smaller like 480px wide or smaller, the span currently stacks like this:

```
gray
orange
red
```

What I would like to do is: if screen size is like iphone landscape view 480px or smaller, then, the order should be:

```
orange
gray
red
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a few different ways to solve this..

**1] Responsive Utility Classes**

If you just have this one use case for your entire site you could use the `.visible-tablet`, `.visible-phone`, etc.. classes [explained here](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive). The downside here is the heavy HTML, but it's fairly simple to do. Working example: http://www.bootply.com/60542

**2] Use jQuery/Javascript to monitor window width**

I'm you don't mind a non-CSS solution you could use jQuery to change the classes accordingly. (You may have cross-browser issues with window.width() too!) For example,

> if $(window).width() < 980) {
>
> ```
>  $('#myRow').removeClass('span6').addClass('span9');
> ```
>
> };
>   ...

**3] Use @media queries to override Bootstrap CSS**

For example this query would change your .row-fluid .span6 to the width of a .row-fluid .span9 (found in bootstrap.css)

```
@media (max-width: 979px) and (min-width: 768px) { /*tablet*/
    .row-fluid .span6 {
    width: 74.46808510638297%; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Skelly! I understand now and I got it to work here:

http://www.getaveo.com/_bootstrap4/_delete3.html

Now, quick question if I may...

If that delete3.html is the solution, now it will have duplicated content. How will this affect SEO? Or it will not matter? Please advise.

Comment: @user2343800 SEO questions are best answered on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/